# Spring Boot - Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

When I tried using WebSocket in my spring boot application I got this error : "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/Moda/chatroomServerEndpoint' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" (Default.html-Line 11).. My aim : Send message by two different tabs (ex: in Google Chrome) Please help me! Thank you...

Default.html

```html
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Deneme</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">

 var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Moda/chatroomServerEndpoint");
 websocket.onmessage = function processMessage(message) {
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.data);
  if(jsonData.message != null) messagesTextArea.value += jsonData.message + "\n";
 }
 function sendMessage(){
  websocket.send(messageText.value);
  messageText.value = "";
 }

</script>

 </head>
 
  <body>
<textarea id="messagesTextArea" readonly = "readonly" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea><br/>
<input type = "text" id="messageText" size="50" /><input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendMessage();" />
   
 </body>
  
  </html>
```

ModaApplication.java

```html
package com.moda;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonWriter;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;



import com.moda.videochat.MyWebSocketConfigurator;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ServerEndpoint("/chatroomServerEndpoint")
public class ModaApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ModaApplication.class, args);
 }
 static Set<Session> chatroomUsers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
 
 @OnOpen
 public void handleOpen(Session userSession)
 {
  chatroomUsers.add(userSession);
 }
 
 @OnMessage
 public void handleMessage(String message, Session userSession) throws IOException {
  String username = (String) userSession.getUserProperties().get("username");
  if(username == null)
  {
   userSession.getUserProperties().get("username");
   userSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData("System","you are now connected as " + message));
  }
  else
  {
   Iterator<Session> iterator = chatroomUsers.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next().getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData(username,message));
  }
 }
 
 @OnClose
 public void handleClose(Session userSession)
 {
  chatroomUsers.remove(userSession);
 }
 
 private String buildJsonData(String username, String message)
 {
  JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("message",username+": "+message).build();
  StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  try (JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(stringWriter)) {jsonWriter.write(jsonObject);}
  return null;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

`new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Moda/chatroomServerEndpoint/websocket");`

instead of

```
`new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Moda/chatroomServerEndpoint");`
```

Also make sure to set `.setAllowedOrigins("*")`

Comment: how set .setAllowedOrigins("*") ? can you give sample ?

Comment: I suppose he was meaning to add that method call inside  WebsocketBrokerConfiguration class, inside registerStompEndpoints class method, like this:  ```registry.addEndpoint("/vrp-websocket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();```

Comment: The problem is Spring Boot will typically not allow setAllowedOrigins("*"). You will need to be more explicit eg setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")

Comment: I can't see any logic behind using the url "ws://localhost:8080/Moda/chatroomServerEndpoint/websocket" when the server end point is "chatroomServerEndpoint". Why do you have to add "/websocket"? However, that is the only way I could get this to work. But I couldn't find any documentation requiring "/websocket" to be added to the endpoint.